# Are flat manifolds affine?

Tags: differential-geometry

I try to understand an article where it is stated that some results regarding affine manifolds apply to the case of the manifold being a flat, compact Lorentzian manifold.

The definition of affine, in this context, is that the manifold has a maximal atlas of charts whose transitions maps extend to affine mappings on ${R}^n$.

My questions:

Is a flat manifold affine? Especially, is a flat Lorentzian manifold affine? Is a compact, flat Lorentzian manifold affine?

Comment: Hope the edits will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An affine manifold is defined a connection whose curvature and torsion forms vanish. If you define by a flat manifold a manifold endowed with a differentiable metric whose curvature vanishes, then such a manifold is affine since the torsion form of a differentiable metric vanishes.
But the fact that only the curvature vanishes does not imply the existence of an affine structure.

Comment: Is there a simple counterexample to that? 

Can compactness help?

Comment: In my text an affine manifold is defined as a manifold whose transition maps extend to affine mappings on ${R}^n$. By 'flat' is meant that the sectional curvature vanishes everywhere. 

Is it an easy thing to show that flat in this sense implies affine?